# How to periodically analyse data on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hive, bigdata

I have a data source generating lots of data all the time,
I put this data periodically to my hadoop cluster.

I want to analyse this data every X minutes but I don't want to execute my analysis over all the data every time,
just want to take last x minutes and analyze it...

I'am putting data to hbase in real time, 
what is the best way to get last x minutes and execute mr job on this data?

Comment: Is loading the data into HBase a requirement? Are you saving the data to HDFS, then loading into HBase, or directly loading the HBase?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I am loading data directly to hbase. It is a requirement.. But, what will be your advice if hbase is not a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using [OOZIE](http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/)? It's a workflow coordination system. It has a concept of coordinators that you can configure to run a Map Reduce job periodically.

You could then use this to run a M/R job that uses HBase as input.

Comment: I think the problem here is that when you insert the data in the HBase, in order to extract only the most recent data, you have to scan all the data.

Comment: Well i that case it will just need an alternative indexing scheme (index on load time as well as the current key), or load the data into HDFS and HBase, HBase for the real-time access, HDFS for the periodic processes.

Comment: I think he could use HBase for the periodic process as well-- load data into two tables: one comprehensive, one "past minute". Then, delete the past minute table when hes done with it or something. If only HBase had partitioning...

Comment: @orangeoctopus I will try your "past minute table" advice, it seems interesting. 
.
ChrisWhite the problem of using hdfs for periodic access is that hdfs does not provide any indexing regarding date. May be I can rename files, or create new folders periodically and than call mr jobs on that folders periodically

Comment: using a folder structure ${year}/${minute}/${day} is how most ETL warehouses work for the raw data ingested. You would then have a job of some decription to extract, transform and load the data into HBase. Assuming you follow this model, you can store off the transformed data into HDFS as well (in a date structured folder too), and then you can easily run these sort of jobs.